# Discord.js removing all member roles

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, roles

I need the bot removes all member roles when I type a command
and here is my code

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    console.log(args);

    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


    if (command == 'مخالف') {
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();

if (!member) return message.channel.send("لم يتم لعثور على العضو");

let drole = member.roles;

member.roles.remove(drole);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the roles to an empty array, removing any roles they had.

```js
member.roles.set([]);
```

[GuildMemberRoleManager#set()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=set)

Comment: im getting error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

Comment: Your bot needs permissions to handle member's roles